# Does "francotiradores" have a historical link to France?

Tags: etimología

I see in the news that the Spanish word for "sniper" is "francotirador"

Is there some historical connection between this and France/Frenchman?

Literally it means "French shooter", right? Were snipers first used by the French foreign legion, or what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only link is that the word itself is a Gallicism; it comes from the French *franc-tireur*.  But here the prefix `franco-` doesn't mean *French* but *free, exempt*. `Francotiradores` are called that way because originally they were irregular soldiers (regular armies didn't have snipers).

See [`franco`, third definition](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IOPRUrf).

Another word with the same prefix is `francmasón` (*freemason*).

Aside from one or two other words (which I can't remember right now), in all other words starting with `franc-`, the prefix very likely means *French*.

Comment: However, _Francia_ and _francés_ have the same root meaning "frank" = libre (free). The French are, etymologically, the free people.

Comment: There is an opera _les francs juges_ which has the translation free not French

Comment: Other words with the Germanic _frank-_ prefix are [franquear](http://dle.rae.es/?w=franquear) (freeing the way), [franquicia](http://dle.rae.es/?w=franquicia) (free from payment) and even the very common [franqueza](http://dle.rae.es/?w=franqueza) (speaking freely).

Comment: In fact, the [first definition for _francotirador_ in the Dictionary of the Real Academia Española](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IOiBucA) is "an irregular fighter", which is the actual meaning in French — the meaning as "someone who shoots from a hidden position" comes after that.

Answer (score 3):

*Francotirador* is a loanword from the French, *franc-tireur*, meaning "free shooter". During the Napoleonic wars, *francs-tireurs* referred to light infantry, or skirmishers who would have fought out of formation ([citation](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/franc-tireur)).

The word acquired its meaning of a partisan, or an irregular soldier who is fighting out of uniform (and therefore exempt from rules regarding treatment of prisoners), during the Franco-Prussian War (1870). During that conflict, members of French shooting clubs, who referred to themselves as *francs-tireurs*, engaged in guerrilla warfare against Prussian troops -- and were summarily executed if captured. During the Second World War, many French Resistance fighters referred to themselves as *franc-tireurs*.

It appears that the Spanish *francotirador* has the original meaning of sniper or sharpshooter, probably acquired during the Peninsular War (1807 - 1814), but not the latter meaning of a partisan or guerrilla. (In fact, so long as I'm mentioning the Peninsular War, I'm going to point out that the word *guerrilla* was popularized in both Spanish and English due to that conflict).

So although there is a connection between the word *francotirador* and France, it's a historical link -- the word doesn't literally mean "French shooter". At least not originally; I wonder how many native speakers would be aware of that.

Comment: To answer your point about how many native know that, I would say not much, native french speakers are a handful few to know that "franc" also means "free".